# Working with the same ReactJS form component on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jsx

I am fairly new to reactJS and I am wondering what's the best way to handle having the same form component on a single page. Please keep in mind that i am using flux and the component is talking to a store.

For example:
    < SearchForm />
    < SearchForm />

When I try to use form #1 input field, Form #2 gets the value from form #1 at the same time. i think the problem is coming from the store. the components are speaking to the same store and the store is updating all the components at once.

How can i handle this problem?

here is the code i have so far.

```
const SearchField = React.createClass({

propTypes: {
    isSearchActivated: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
},

_onChange() {
    var previousHighlightedIndex = this.state.highlightedIndex;
    this.setState(getStateFromStores(), function() {
        if (previousHighlightedIndex == 0 &&
                this.state.highlightedIndex == -1) {
            this.refs.SearchBar.selectAll();
        }
    });
},

componentDidMount() {
    if (window.location.pathname == "/" && !Modernizr.mq("screen only and (max-width: 768px)")) {
        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.SearchBar)).find("input").focus();
    }
},

componentWillUnmount() {
    SearchResultStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
},

onChangeSearchString(e) {
    SearchResultsUtils.search(e.target.value);
},

onBlur(e) {
    var self = this;
    var cb = function() {
        if (!self.state.selectedResult && self.state.results.length) {
            self.handleSelectedResult(0);
        }

        SearchResultsActions.disallowResultsDisplay();
    };
    if($(".search-bar").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".search-bar.active").removeClass("active");
    }
},

onFocus(e) {
    $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.SearchBar)).closest(".search-bar").addClass("active");
},

handleSubmit() {
    var self = this;
},

render() {
    var className = "search-bar clearfix";

    return (
        <div className={className}>
            <div className="search-bar-search">
                <SearchBar
                    searchString={this.state.searchString}
                    onChange={this.onChangeSearchString}
                    onKeyDown={this.onKeyDownSearchString}
                    onFocus={this.onFocus}
                    onBlur={this.onBlur}
                    placeholder="Search Meds or Conditions"
                    ref="SearchBar" />
            </div>

            <SearchButton
                handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
        </div>
    );
},
});

module.exports = SearchField;
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you add your code? Sounds like both forms share the same state.

Comment: If you really have plain `<SearchForm/> <SearchForm/>`, then react cannot cause form #2 to be updated when you enter something in form #1. Your tags also mention jQuery. Are you by any chance using jQuery to update the form? Then this is more likely the source of your issue. (And you really should not mix jQuery and react in this way). Could you add more code to your question?

Comment: i updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can reuse your components multiple times across your application.

**1.If you do not want to have any state:**

In your situation you can provide form submit handler as callback prop. If you do not want to maintain any state on your search form.
e.g
For form 1

```
<Searchform submitHandler={searchForm1Handler}/>
```

For form 2

```
<Searchform submitHandler={searchForm2Handler}/>
```

and Inside your search form component

```
render(){
  return (
     <form id="searchform" onSubmit={this.props.submitHandler} role="form">
      // other input and buttons
     </form>
   )
}
```

**2. With states**

With this approach each component will have its own separate states which will be private to them.

Here is sample component to illustrate this

```
import React ,{ Component } from 'react';

export default class SearchForm extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchTerm : ''
        };
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
        this.changeSearchTerm = this.changeSearchTerm.bind(this);
    }

    submit(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        let searchTerm = this.state.searchTerm;
        //Now perform some action based on search term you get
    }

    changeSearchTerm(e){
        this.setState({searchTerm :e.target.value});
    }

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-12">
                      <form role="form" className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={this.submit}>
                        <fieldset>
                          <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                <input id="st" type="text" placeholder="search term" onChange={this.changeSearchTerm} value={this.state.searchTerm} required autofocus/>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div className="form-group">
                             <div className="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                 <button className="btn">
                                 Search
                                 </button>
                           </div>
                          </div>
                        </fieldset>
                      </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now to use them

For form 1

```
<Searchform/>
```

For form 2

```
<Searchform/>
```

Answer (score 0):

React has stateful components:

> a component can maintain internal state data (accessed via this.state)

which allows you to have `<SearchForm />#1` with `value1`, and `<SearchForm />#2` with `value2` stored in `this.state`

To build a form, check this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: how would you set it ? can you give me an example code snippet please.

Comment: see @WitVault answer which is greate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552422/working-with-the-same-reactjs-form-component-on-the-same-page/36554606#36554606

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your store only saves one state - which includes search value - for one form.
If you render this form twice, then both forms retrieve the same state on each change. So they are an exact copy of each other by design. If one form changes, both forms notice the change, and both forms will retrieve the exact same state from the store.

To fix this, I would suggest:

- change the store so that it can save a state for multiple forms, each with its own ID
- pass this ID to each form as a prop, e.g. `<SearchForm formID='form1'/> <SearchForm formID='form2'/>`
- pass the `formID` down as a prop to all children of the form, such as `<SearchField>`
- inside the `<SearchField>`, make sure your component only renders state from its own `formID`. You probably need to update the `getStateFromStores()` method itself. Or inside `<SearchField>` filter out relevant stuff first, before passing it to `setState()`.
- when your component informs the store that something has changed (I guess this is what `SearchResultsUtils.search(e.target.value);` does), then you need to pass the `formID` as well. So the store will know which form to update.

PS: I think your code is missing some lines in `componentDidMount()`: you have code to remove the listener to store changes, but your code to add the listener is missing. The code to invoke the `_onChange()` method is missing from your component.